# How to debug field in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to debug class field, the things I want to know is: 
who and when changed the variable. But it seems that it doesn't work like a regular break point, whenever the field gets changed my application just stops and there is not such option as Step Over or Resume Program in debug window. My tool bar looks unusable:
[image]

So, as you can see from the Overhead the field was hit once, and my application stopped afterwards. Also it doesn't show who changed a variable, or how it was changed(via setter or from inside class). How can I make it work?

Comment: it seems that android is collecting data or evaluating expressions at the time you take snap shot.

Comment: else android studio does have step into or step over functionality via f8 and f9 you achieve the same respectively.

Comment: why not include a breakpoint every time (via setter or from inside class) value is updated for the variable ! This way before your app stops working unexpectedly, the flow will stop at the breakpoint and you would how and where to fix

Comment: see `"add watchpoint"` - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#watchpoints - they say it works in c/c++ only, but i am pretty sure you can use it in java as well (but not 100% sure)

Comment: You can try [watchpoints.](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#watchpoints) with using breakpoints on maximum lines.

Answer (score 0):

Both "Add watchpoint" and adding breakpoints every time value is updated almost did the trick.Actually, None of the breakpoints were triggered at all, but it led me to conclusion that the application was not using the correct object at all, and yes, the hashcodes of used object and the object that application 
should have used were different, should be more carefull with singleton :)